# Añadir clase a un componente al cambiar otro componente

Tags: angular, angular5

veréis estoy programando una web en Angular5. En principio es una web muy sencilla, pero ando un poco perdido en un detalle. La estructura del app.component.html es así:

```html
<app-header></app-header>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Entonces el problema es que quiero cambiar el color del header y el footer dependiendo de la sección. Claro al principio pensé en usar @Outlet desde el componente al iniciarse su ciclo de vida y con un @Input desde el header recoger la variable y cambiar el color desde el componente, pero estoy leyendo que el eventEmitter tiene que ejecutar el la funcion en la etiqueta del componente, pero yo no la tengo porque la carga el router-outlet así que no tengo ni idea de como solucionarlo, ando muy perdido.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Lo suyo seria crear un servicio intermedio y un observable en el, desde el componente header y footer te suscribes a este observable y cambias la clase de acuerdo a lo que recibas del observable.
Como el codigo es algo largo te dejo un stackblitz para que puedas verlo mejor y experimentar con el.

En mi caso el componente Hello llama a una funcion en el servicio intermedio lo cual cambia el tema y manda un mensaje al observable al cual ambos componentes estan suscritos

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-observable)

Vale mencionar que una vez que no necesites el observable te desuscribas